# Uploading Large PDF Files in Sharepoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, pdf, sharepoint-rest-api

I want to upload large PDF Files in a Sharepoint Library .

I tried from normal code from `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` method and it is working fine , but taking too much time.(for ex. a PDF of size 200 MB will take 16 minutes.)

I also Tried this link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx#Anchor_2

But No Such Impact is seen in Uploading Time. 
In fact, for 200 MB file, it crashes the browser.

Is there any other method through which we can compress the file and upload it in SharePoint library OR Upload without Compressing it in Short Span of time.

Main Priority is to reduce **FILE Uploading Time**.

Comment: I think that uploading through PowerShell would be faster, omitting the extra layer of the browser. But I'm not sure...

Comment: It will take some time, but you should probably look into chunk upload. Have a look at the [OfficeDev PnP for large file upload](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/articles/Upload-large-files-sample-app-for-SharePoint.md)

Comment: @AndersAune  but this is in CSOM , i want in JSOM or REST ..

Comment: @AdarshGumashta true, but you could use the startupload, continueupload, finishupload with REST to chunk